# npm got Segmentation fault at linux

Tags: node.js, npm

- **linux version:**

> ```
> [root@etone231 download]# lsb_release -a
> LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch
> Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
> Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.1 (Tikanga)
> Release:        5.1
> Codename:       Tikanga
> ```

- **node.js:**

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
> cd node
> ./configure
> make
> sudo make install
> ```

- **npm fail:**

> ```
> [root@etone231 download]# node -e "console.log('a')"
> a
>
> [root@etone231 download]# node -v
> v0.8.6
>
> [root@etone231 download]# python -V
> Python 2.7.3
>
> [root@etone231 download]# gmake -v
> GNU Make 3.81
> Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
> There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
> PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
>
> [root@etone231 download]# npm -v
> 1.1.48
>
> [root@etone231 download]# npm list
> Segmentation fault
> ```